# Object and Classes: Finding balance ,annual interest rate, monthly interest rate, withdrawing, depositing

Tags: java

Instructions: Design a class named Account that contains:

A private int data field named id for the account ( default 0).

1. A private double data field named balance for the account ( default 0).
2. A private constant double data field named annualInterestRate that stores the current interest rate of 12%.  Assume all accounts have the same interest rate.
3. A private Date data field named dateCreated that stores the date when the account was created.
4. A no-arg constructor that creates a default account.
5. A constructor that creates an account with the specified id and initial balance.
6. The accessor (setter) and mutator (getter) methods for id, balance, and annualInterestRate.
7. The accessor method for dateCreated.
8. A method named getMonthlyInterestRate() that returns the monthly interest rate in as a percentage.  For example it returns 1, not .01, for a 1% monthly rate.
9. A method named getMonthlyInterest() that returns the monthly interest.
10. A method named withdraw that withdraws a specified amount from the account.
11. A method named deposit that deposits a specified amount to the account.

Create a project file in Bluej and implement the class. ( Hint: The method getMonthlyInterest() is to return monthly interest, not the interest rate. Monthly interest is balance * monthlyInterestRate. monthlyInterestRate is annualInterestRate /1200.

Test the program using BlueJ.  You should test each of the methods making sure that they are working properly.

Write a second class called AccountTester which contains the main method.  The account tester should do the following in this order:

1. Create an account object
2. Display the account balance
3. Display the annualInterestRate
4. Deposit $150
5. Display the account balance
6. Withdraw $50
7. Display the account balance
8. Deposits the monthly interest
9. Display the account balance

Here is my following code. I have errors I am just not sure how to fix them. Any help/tips would be appreciated

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Date;

public class Account
{
    private int id = 0;
    private double balance = 0;
    final private double annualinterestrate = 0.12;
    Date dateCreated;

    public Account()
    {

    }

    public Account(int aId, double aBalance, double annualInterestRate)
    {
        id = aId;
        balance = aBalance;
        annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
        dateCreated = new Date();
    }

    public void setID (int aId)
    {
        id = aId;
    }

    public int getID()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setBalance (double aBalance)
    {
        balance = aBalance;
    }

    public double getbalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setAnnualInterestRate (double aannualInterestRate)
    {
        annualInterestRate = aannualInterestRate;
    }

    public double getAnnualInterestRate()
    {
        return annualInterestRate;
    }

    public Date getDateCreated()
    {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public double getMonthlyInterestRate()
    {
        return annualInterestRate / 12;
    }

    public void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        balance -= amount;
    }

    public void deposit(double amount)
    {
        balance += amount;
    }
}
```

Then here is the second class code which contains the main method:

```
public class AccountTester
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Account account = new Account(1857, 5000, 0.12);

        account.setID(1857);
        account.setBalance(5000);
        account.setAnnualInterestRate(0.12);



        System.out.println ("Account number: \n"+ +account.getID());
        System.out.println ("The account balance is: $ \n" + +account.getbalance());
        System.out.println("The Annual Interest Rate is: $ \n" + account.getannualInteresrRate());
        account.deposit(150);
        System.out.println("The account balance is: $ \n" +account.getbalance());
        account.withdraw(50);
        System.out.println("The account balance is: $ \n" +account.getbalance());
        System.out.println ("The monthly interest earned is: $ \n" + +account.getbalance() *    account.annualInterestRate());
        System.out.println ("The account was created on: \n" + +account.getdateCreated());

    }
}
```

Comment: By now, you've had a fair amount of experience posting questions in which others have asked you to post the errors you're receiving. We can't possibly know what problem(s) you're having if all you say is "I'm getting errors".

Comment: cannot find symbol "aId" in the Account class in the public Account(int id, double balance, double annualInterestRate) method

Comment: Look **very** closely at the parameter names of that constructor (same problem is also occurring in the `setId` method).

Comment: @Paul And `setBalance`, and `setAnnualInterestRate`... Curiously, it's exactly the same error everywhere.

Comment: Frequently, "cannot find symbol" errors mean that you've got a typo somewhere and as a result a variable is named incorrectly. In this case, all over the place.

Comment: @HenryKeiter Ah yep, you're right, didn't realize how widespread the problem was. Those methods too, Tanner11.

Comment: cannot find symbol -variable annualInterestRate in my public void setAnnualInterestRate(double aannualInterestRate) method

Comment: @Tanner11 Also, I suspect you have forgotten how the `this` reference works. It will help you to avoid having to name variables differently in a method (ex: `this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate` etc etc)

Comment: I saw that online the other day when researching this topic, but we have not learned that in our class so I didn't think I should use it until the professor went over it

Comment: **Please do not edit answers into your question!** It invalidates the answers and is confusing for future visitors to the site. If you have new questions, post them as new questions (but in this particular case, you just need to look at your spelling everywhere and fix it *carefully*. StackOverflow is not a substitute for careful coding!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current issue is that you didn't use camelCasedNames when you defined the `annualInterestRate` field, so it doesn't exist! It's currently named `annualinterestrate` instead (note there are no caps!). You ought to rename it to match what you're using elsewhere.

Also, that field in particular has another problem, which is that you've declared it `final`. That means you can't modify it after the object is created, so your `setAnnualInterestRate` method is doomed to fail anyway unless you remove the `final` modifier. So that field declaration should look like this:

```
private double annualInterestRate = 0.12;
```

---

Your naming conventions in general are obviously giving you some serious grief. You indicated in the comments that you don't want to use the `this` keyword since your instructor hasn't introduced it yet, and that's fine, but you should at least name your variables in some way that it's **obvious from looking at it** what's going on and whether it will work. Prefixing variable names with a lowercase `"a"` is not the answer. Instead, consider a *meaningful* prefix or suffix if you need to avoid naming conflicts. For example:

```
public void setBalance (double newBalance)
{
    balance = newBalance;
}
```

---

You've got other spelling errors elsewhere, including in your `AccountTester` class. You need to go through your code carefully and make sure the names match up exactly. Working with an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans with live compilation warnings and auto-completion will likely save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: okay thanks for your input. I removed the final, but what field should I rename?

Comment: You need to rename `annualinterestrate` to match the capitalization that you're using elsewhere (`annualInterestRate`). Capitalization matters. Two variables named `a` and `A` are **not** the same!

Comment: okay I thought I did that and it still is saying it cannot find the variable annualInterestRate

Comment: @Tanner11 If the compiler can't find it, that means it's not there. Look very closely at all your spellings. Based on the fact that you just edited a bunch of new errors into your question without touching the thing you needed to fix, I'm betting you haven't actually fixed anything yet. *You need to go over your code carefully and fix all your spelling.* You have problems in the `AccountTester` class as well.